# New to Coding - How do I Save Substrings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, substring

I am trying to learn how to code and I am working on CodeAcademy.com. I am trying to learn how to save a Substring in Javascript. My assignment is:

"This time we're going to get the first three letters of your name. See if you can save those letters to a variable named three using the substring() method from above. Remember that your name variables from before are no longer stored in memory."

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
var myName
myName = "Dave"
var three
three.substring(0,3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Dave

Comment: Which language ? .NET, PHP, Ruby .. other ??

Comment: can you include the language you are learning ?

Comment: I think it is Java. I believe I figured it out:
var three = myName.substring(0,3)
Thanks!

Comment: from looking at CodeAcademy.com, it seems to be in Javascript

Comment: @DaveGerhart do you know how bad it is to "learn a language" then say "I think this langauge im learning is Java". Your wrong, its javascript. You really need to appreciate that knowing the name of the language is kind of important

Comment: @Raynos Thanks for the reply! I agree it is horrible not to know the language, but in the first lesson on Codeacademy.com, it doesn't say which language you will be learning. That is why I said "I think it is Javascript." Since I am new to coding, I just don't what is out there and if I knew what I was coding in, I would have said.

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
three = myName.substring (0, 3);
```

The `.substring` method can be used on a string so, if you want to get the first 3 letters from `myName`, the method should be used on *it,* rather than `three`.

The return value from that substring operation is then *assigned* to `three`.